# How to change specific ngClass with same selector/identifier in angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

CSS

```
<style>
    .focused{
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{focused: hasFocus}">
   <input type="text" ng-focus="hasFocus = true" ng-blur='hasFocus = false'>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{focused: hasFocusOther}">
    <input type="text" ng-focus="hasFocusOther = true" ng-blur='hasFocusOther = false'>
</div>
```

How can i simplify my code to use only one selector without triggering ng-class in both form-group. and only use "hasFocus" on each group.

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{focused: hasFocus}">
   <input type="text" ng-focus="hasFocus = true" ng-blur='hasFocus = false'>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{focused: hasFocus}">
    <input type="text" ng-focus="hasFocus= true" ng-blur='hasFocus= false'>
</div>
```

any other solution would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with one variable for each field same as the way tab is active each time one tab is clicked. We just **need to handle which item is active each time one is blurred**.

I expect you are displaying all input fields by ng-repeat. I made a variable named activeFocus which will be a field of item in collection of ng-repeat. **Each time blur event happen, activeFocus of active item will be true.**

**Code for rendering:**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in listItem" class="form-group" ng-class="{focused: item.activeFocus}">
    <input type="text" ng-focus="item.activeFocus" ng-blur='changeFocus(item)'>
</div>
```

**Function for change focus:**

```
$scope.changeFocus = function(itemActive){
   // deactive all except item
   listItem = listItem.map(function(item){
       // activeFocus == true when item == itemActive
       item.activeFocus = item == itemActive;
       return item;
   })
}
```